# Prevent div from scrolling to top when inner div is given focus - IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an outer div with `style.overflow` set to `auto`. It contains a larger child div which causes the outer div to become scrollable.

When the outer div is scrolled to the bottom, giving focus to the inner div causes the scroll position to return to top left (0,0). This happens only on IE 11. A working example of the issue is provided through the link below (the div is given focus when clicked)

https://jsfiddle.net/wy6u8b76/6/

Is there a way to prevent the window from scrolling to the top?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by pre-setting the scrollTop to 0, and then moving the margin so it remains in the same location. Finally you can undo all of this insanity.

Here's your modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/2n1f25nk/1/

```
document.getElementById('div1').onclick = function() {
  var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
  var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
  var scrollTop = div1.scrollTop;
  div2.style.marginTop = (-scrollTop) + 'px';
  div1.scrollTop = 0;
  // give focus to inner div
  document.getElementById('div2').focus();
  // Undo the horribleness
  div2.style.marginTop = '0px';
  div1.scrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

Comment: Try using `setActive`.  It's like "focus" without the scrolling, and it is ONLY available in IE. Here's a link to another post where I describe how I'm using it to accomplish basically the same thing.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901431/ie11-focusing-child-div-causes-parent-to-scroll-to-top/40923837#40923837